# How can I mock any function which is not being called directly?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

#### TL;DR

How can I patch or mock **"any functions that are not being called/used directly"**?

#### Sceneario

I have a simple unit-test snippet as

```
# utils/functions.py
def get_user_agents():
    # sends requests to a private network and pulls data
    return pulled_data


# my_module/tasks.py
def create_foo():
    from utils.functions import get_user_agents
    value = get_user_agents()
    # do something with value
    return some_value


# test.py
class TestFooKlass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        create_foo()

    def test_foo(self):
        ...
```

Here in **`setUp()`** method I am calling **`get_user_agents()`** function ***indirectly*** by calling **`create_foo()`**. During this execution I have got **`socket.timeout`** exception since **`get_user_agents()`** tried to access a private network. 
So, how can I manipulate the return data or the entire `get_user_agents` function during the test?

Also, is there any way to persists this mock/patch during the whole test suite execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not matter that you call the function indirectly - important is to patch it [as it is imported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). In your example you import the function to be patched locally inside the tested function, so it will only be imported at function run time. In this case you have to patch the function as imported from its module (e.g. `'utils.functions.get_user_agents'`):

```py
class TestFooKlass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = mock.patch('utils.functions.get_user_agents',
                                  return_value='foo')  # whatever it shall return in the test 
        self.patcher.start()  # this returns the patched object, i  case you need it
        create_foo()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()

    def test_foo(self):
        ...
```

If you had imported the function instead at module level like:

```py
from utils.functions import get_user_agents

def create_foo():
    value = get_user_agents()
    ...
```

you should have patched the imported instance instead:

```py
        self.patcher = mock.patch('my_module.tasks.get_user_agents',
                                  return_value='foo')
```

As for patching the module for all tests: you can start patching in `setUp` as shown above, and stop it in `tearDown`.

Comment: Is there realy a need for an explicite call of `self.patcher.stop()`? Isn't called when the TestCase and its `self.patcher` is destroyed at the end? It would help to have some context-manager like solution for the forgetful developers like me. ;)

Comment: Well, there are context managers for indivual tests (both the `patch` decorator and the `with patch...` construct), and you can use these in pytest fixtures, where both setup and teardown are done in the same fixture (one of the nice things about pytest), but not for `unittest`, AFAIK. And stopping is important because you may run other tests in the same session - the patcher does not stop on destroy, AFAIK.

Comment: Maybe `addClassCleanup()` is a solution. I will check this out. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addClassCleanup

Comment: Yes, you could do this (if you use `setUpClass`, otherwise it would be `addCleanup()`), but if you are already thinking about it, you could also implement `tearDown` :) Or use pytest - pytest actually _does_ the cleanup automatically if you forget it.

Comment: Works for me! @MrBeanBremen gives the effective answer to the problem: "*you should have patched the imported instance instead*". That is, the path in "mock.patch" must be "my_module.tasks.get_user_agents". **But, I would really appreciate to know why in this particular case things work this way!** 